# Nginx Proxy Cache Key not saving variants of query params

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx configuration which has the following code for the `/` location:

```
    location = / {
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip on;
      gzip_types text/xml text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript;
      gzip_disable (gozilla|traviata);
      gzip_min_length 1400;
      gzip_comp_level 9;
      proxy_cache index_cache;
      proxy_pass http://nodejs;
      proxy_cache_key $proxy_host$uri?$arg_id&$arg_toggle-on&$arg_toggle-off;

      set $nocache 0;

      if ($arg_id = "") {
        set $nocache 1;
      }

      if ($arg_number) {
        set $nocache 1;
      }

      proxy_no_cache $nocache;
    }
```

The `id` query param consists of an integer, usually 1-4 digits long.

The `toggle-on` and `toggle-off` query params contain strings which are separated by commas for each toggle.

For example, I could have:

`https://mywebsite.com/?id=1234&toggle-on=animations,fields,experiments&toggle-off=control`

Where `toggle-on` would then evaluate the `animations`, `fields`, and `experiment` strings on its own within the code.

However, I'm finding that for some reason I'm not able to properly cache this at all.

The `id` field is cached properly -- Nginx knows the difference between one ID and another (the UI for this site changes dynamically based on this value).

The `toggle-on` and `toggle-off` ones, however, do not. They don't properly cache exactly *which values* are assigned to each query param when provided.

What can I dig deeper into so that I can become a bit less stuck here?